# How save all changes in local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm trying to create an editable listview. You can add and eliminate elements of the list. Each element have a group of elements.

How can I save all the changes of the list in local storage?

I need save the changes of the listview (add/eliminate items) and the the data of the all the inputs text of the list.

here is my code:

```
  $(document).on("click", ".fila", function () {
    $(this).next().next(".cuadro").slideToggle();
  });

$(document).on("click", ".borrar", function () {
    $( this ).parent( "li" ).remove();
    $( "#list1" ).listview( "refresh" );
  });
 $(document).on("click", "#btn2", function () {
  var content =
              "<li>" +
              "<a href='#' class='fila'>elemento1</a><a href='#' data-icon='delete' class='borrar'>Favorita</a><div class='cuadro'><label>label:</label><input type='text' value='' maxlength='3'/><label >label2:</label><select data-role='slider'><option value='off'>Off</option><option value='on'>On</option></select></div>" +
              "</li>";

  $( content ).appendTo( "#list1" ).enhanceWithin();
  $( "#list1" ).listview( "refresh" );

});
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juank_romero/hA8Ps/11/

Comment: $(form).serialize() might give you a head start

Answer (score 1):

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hA8Ps/13/)

Use **[HTML localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)**.

```
//Append preivously stored elements.
$("#list1").html(localStorage.getItem('content'))

$(document).on("click", ".fila", function () {
    $(this).next().next(".cuadro").slideToggle();
});

$(document).on("click", ".borrar", function () {
    $(this).parent("li").remove();
    localStorage.setItem('content', $("#list1").html());
    $("#list1").listview("refresh");
});
$(document).on("click", "#btn2", function () {
    var content =
        "<li>" +
        "<a href='#' class='fila'>elemento1</a><a href='#' data-icon='delete' class='borrar'>Favorita</a><div class='cuadro'><label>label:</label><input type='text' value='' maxlength='3'/><label >label2:</label><select data-role='slider'><option value='off'>Off</option><option value='on'>On</option></select></div>" +
        "</li>";

    //store elements
    $(content).appendTo("#list1").enhanceWithin();
    localStorage.setItem('content', $("#list1").html());
    $("#list1").listview("refresh");

});
```

Comment: This code works perfect to save when you add some element to the list. But when i delete one element of the list, doesnt works. How can i save also all the input text´s of the list??

Comment: updated the code..please check. you just need to add local storage set to remove() code.

Comment: Thank you :) each list item have inside some elements. when i add one of it if you click on it you see what its inside. but when i uptdate the page the item its saved correctly but inside of it something is wrong because you see like a duplicate inside of each element. What its the problem?? thanks for your help :) here is the the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/hA8Ps/14/

Comment: im testing the code but i found something wired. When i load the list from the local storage the items works, but the elements that are inside (when you click on it) doesn´t work (a on/off slider its wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Take the data you want saved.

`JSON.stringify` it
and then use the [`localStorage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

localStorage uses string key value pairs that's why you JSON.stringify your data and then give it a name and set it in localStorage and you're golden.